# Icon showing twice on action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I added an icon logo to the action bar positioned at the top left but when I run one of the activities it is duplicated on both sides of the action bar.Does anyone have a quick fix for this issue? I looked at the layout file for the action bar and I have placed it at the top left so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong with the setup of the button attributes.

How action bar layout should look:

[image: original]

The probelm is that the green logo is shown on the right side but it should only be on the left as in the above picture:

[image: Problem]

The layout is as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/action_bar_staff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_help" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_staff"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/appicon" />
```

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, you want the button with the id action_bar_home to do what?

Comment: The first picture is how that action bar should look.But when I navigate to another activity the green logo is duplicated on the right hand side,which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make it like this:

```
<!-- First your Home icon align Left/Top -->
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/appicon" />  

<!-- Your Help icon align Right/Top -->
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_help" />

<!-- Finally your Back icon align Top/toRightOf -->
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_staff"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back" />
```

It should works. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but now the help icon has disappeared,not sure why?

Comment: But your Help and Back icons are good positionned, not? And when you remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to Home icon, what happens?

Comment: If I remove this I get the same as the screenshot in the question.When I add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" the help icon is not there..

Comment: What's your `RelativeLayout`? Try my update I think `Button` with `drawable` must to be define with `ImageButton`.